# JQuery Validate Plugin Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using the JQuery Validation plugin for a form. It works perfectly for Chrome, however, it does not work at all for Safari. I am not sure why this would be the case. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form" action="index.php" method="post">
    <?php if ($good_input){ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
            Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you as soon as possible.
            </div>
   <?php } ?>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name*</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="comments">Comments*</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea rows="5" name="comments" required></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-submit">
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my jQUERY validation code:

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$("#contact-form").validate();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Validate plugin follows the jQuery JavaScript in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Its because Safari does not support HTML5 Forms Validation like the other web browsers do, for some reason the developers do not see the greatness of HTML5 and how it makes submitting forms so much easier then having to work out functions to check and see if the browser is Safari, so has of right now I think it is because Safari does not support HTML5 Forms or I can't find it any way because I was/having the same problem.